# Not able to populate a table from the output of a function

Tags: sql-server, function, datatable

I am unable to populate my table from the output of my function. I have three columns in my table namely, EmpId,Dates,EmpName. The columns EmpId and EMpName are static values which are getting populated fine but the column Dates has to be populated through a function. However, when I try to do the same I am getting a syntax error.

Please Find below the query I am using

```
INSERT INTO Dbo.LeaveDates (EmpId,[Date],EmpName) VALUES(@EmpId,MyDate,@Emp_Name)
Select MyDate from [dbo].[ListDates](CONVERT(CHAR, @FromDate),CONVERT(CHAR, @ToDate))
```

The error I am getting is also under:

> *The name "MyDate" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables.
>   Column names are not permitted.
>   *

I have declared all variables in question

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO Dbo.LeaveDates (EmpId,[Date],EmpName) 
SELECT @EmpId, MyDate, @Emp_Name 
FROM [dbo].[ListDates](CONVERT(CHAR, @FromDate),CONVERT(CHAR, @ToDate))
```

Your query consists essentially of two *separate* sql statements. An `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO Dbo.LeaveDates (EmpId,[Date],EmpName) 
VALUES(@EmpId,MyDate,@Emp_Name)
```

followed by a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT MyDate 
FROM [dbo].[ListDates](CONVERT(CHAR, @FromDate),CONVERT(CHAR, @ToDate))
```

`INSERT` fails because, as the error message clearly states, `MyDate` is not permitted in this context, i.e. as a separate column name, without being selected from a table.